# Not able to see Notification on android 12

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, push-notification, android-12

Had a unity application, once upgraded to android api-level 31. Not able to see or receive push notification.

Tried exported=true to messaging activity, updated the unity firebase-sdk. Nothing worked

Comment: Add more info.. from which version to which version you updated? Did you updated any dependencies? Did you add firebasemessage service in manifest.. did you check their official docs once to updated to 31?